# Is there a way to change the categorical variables in tbl_summary from displaying as {p}% to proportions?

Tags: gtsummary

Is there a way to change the categorical variables in `tbl_summary` from displaying as {p}% to proportions?

An example, instead of showing 48%, it will be 0.48. I tried style_percent and style number without any look. I also tried `datasummary` but it didn't work and I couldn't display the standard deviation under the average in parentheses.

```
tbl_summary(data = CPS, by = "Type",
                          include = c(Female, Hispanic,
                                      age,
                                      DadGradCollege,
                                      MomGradCollege,
                                      ftotval_def
                                      ),
                          statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} \n({sd})",
                                           all_categorical() ~ "{p}%"),
                          label = list(
                            Female~ "Female",
                            Hispanic ~ "Hispanic",
                            age ~ "Age",
                            DadGradCollege ~ "Fathers with \n \t College", 
                            MomGradCollege ~ "Mothers with \n \t College",
                            ftotval_def ~ "Total Family Income \n \t (1999 dollars)"
                            ),
                          missing = "no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use the `digits=` argument to pass functions that will style/round/format the statistics. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.2'

trial |> 
  tbl_summary(
    include = grade,
    statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}",
    digits = all_categorical() ~ function(x) style_number(x, digits = 2)
  ) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable for SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 200** |
| --- | --- |
| Grade |  |
| I | 0.34 |
| II | 0.34 |
| III | 0.32 |

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>