# Is it possible to modify gtsummary's big mark separator for only one line in the table?

Tags: r, gtsummary, gt

is it possible to remove the big mark separator just for one line in the table?
The only 4 digits values in my table are in fact years and I get them with the default , separator for big marks.

Thanks

In simple example below there is a Year variable which does not really make sense with big mark separator.

```
test1 <- data.frame(
              Country = c("Italy","Italy","Italy",
                          "Netherlands","Netherlands","Netherlands"),
    Duration = c(47L, 28L, 23L, 37L, 16L, 29L),
   Year = c(1959, 1961, 1969, 1970, 1956, 1975)
         )

#table
tab1 <- test1 %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by =  Country,
    type = list(c(Duration, Year) ~ "continuous"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(all_continuous() ~ 1, all_categorical()~ 0)
  ) %>% add_overall()
```

I searched whether gtsummary supported year and/or dates but I only found continuous/categorical. Also tried to have a look in to tab1$table_body tab1$table_styling but could not find any clear command re big mark

Comment: Why not just make Year a character column by adding the line `mutate(Year = as.character(Year)) %>%` after `test1 %>%`. That is presumably easier than trying to create bespoke per-row formatting?

Comment: Check out this post to see how to change the rounding/formatting function for one variable in a table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321464/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-categorical-variables-in-tbl-summary-from-displayin/74321560#74321560